# how can i apply width from css and not from html progress tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set progress bar width from css. is there any way to do that?
Here's the test example for firefox from jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dfkLexuv/

html

```
<progress class="progressBar" value="50" max="100">50 %</progress>
```

css

```
.progressBar::-moz-progress-bar{
  background-color: red;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: there is no any code in jsfiddle link !!!

Comment: forgot to save. Please try now

Comment: ok but i post my ans ..

Comment: @User7354632781 Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @dippas why is this duplicate? _I am trying to set progress bar **width** from css_

Comment: @User7354632781 .. Check The My Snippet Ans ....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can edit a `progress` tag's `value` amount with CSS, but you could make your own "custom" progress bar with two `div`s, like this.

```css
.progress-bar-outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  
  background-color: gray;
}

.progress-bar-inner {
  height: 100%;

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  float: left
}

.red {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 35%;
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  /* You can change the `width` to change the amount of progress. */
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar-outer">
  <div class="progress-bar-inner red">
  </div>

  <!-- Multiple bars can be placed next to each other! -->
  <div class="progress-bar-inner green">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i add one more css class say `.progress-bar-inner2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: green;
} ` can i stack both progress bars next to each other